# loading dependent jars using <applet> or <object> tag

Tags: java, caching, applet, loading

I am here with a peculiar problem while loading applets.
My applet is dependent on 2 jar files, so I am using "cache-archive" and "archive" param tags to point to jars.

Say my applet is embedded in a.jar and is dependent on dep1.jar(size in KB only) & dep2.jar(size 3MB) respectively.
While loading my applet a.jar, dep1.jar loaded successfully but dep2.jar failed to load and throws ClassNotFoundException.

When I tried to load a sample applet jar with no dependent jars, I am able to load the applet successfully with both  as well as  tags.

Now comes the interesting part, applet load failure happens only when JAVA PLUGIN CONTROL has the setting "caching enabled" ONLY. If caching is disabled, then applet is getting loaded without any issues.

I hope you got the problem by this time, I am trying to programmatically delete the java plugin cache and load the jars afresh, as I cannot go and say my users to delete the java plugin cache manually.

Question: Is there any way to programmatically delete the java plugin control cache. And also can any one let me know why dep2.jar fails to load when java plugin control settings enabled to cache the resources.

Appreciation inadvance.

Comment: question repeated in a separated phrase now

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to modify the client's file cache from your application. Also, it sounds like you are running into versioning issues with the cache. To combat this, you need to ensure your JNLP and associated jars are using proper versioning techniques.